# php url validator shows valid address as not valid

Tags: php, url-validation

```
if (!filter_var($site, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED))...
```

This validator shows:
https://www.g - as valid address !
www.google.com - as invalid address !

If you type some address into address bar, and you see that it works - it should be a valid address.  And vice versa.  I need such one validator.
Or - I'm missing something in the above code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A user comment on [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php) states:

"Please note that FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED and FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED have disappeared. They were previously mentioned in the constants page but it seems that host and scheme are now required by default for the validate_url filter."

Seems like the protocol is a must with recent PHP versions and cannot be disabled.

Answer (score 4):

`www.google.com` is not a valid url. It needs a protocol for it to be valid i.e. `http://www.google.com`

Comment: Musa, I can't expect from user (during registration) that in the `You site` form input - type http...

Comment: @ithcy, yes, I can. But I expect that the validator do that.

Comment: @Alegro validators are for validating, not modifying. They only answer the question "is this correct?"

Comment: Also please note that `http://www.g` is a valid URL. It's not a valid *internet* URL, as `g` is not a valid TLD, but it is valid.

Comment: @Alegro you're going to have to add a default protocol if not is specified then validate the url.

Comment: @Musa, ok, I can and I will do. But can't figure that php cannot do it instead of me